# viewのマスクについて

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

【解決済みです】
Xcode7.1・swiftを用いたios向けアプリケーションの練習中として、[こちら](http://lab.spec5zigen.com/archives/calayer/)のサイト冒頭の「左右がジワっと消える」UIScrollViewを制作したいと思い、コード制作・苦戦しておりました。

[英語版stackOverFlowに似たような質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091998/how-to-mask-a-uiscrollview)がありましたので、参考にしました。
UIViewにマスクを施し、その中でUIScrollViewを動かす事で、UIScrollViewの状態に関係無くマスクをかける事に成功しました事をお伝え致します。

作成していたUIScrollViewは、0~9までの画像(元500x500を80x80にしたもの)をダイヤルのようにグルグルとループさせる文です。

参考までに、作成したマスクのコードを置いておきます。

```
(maskUIView.swift)
import UIKit
class maskUIView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let maskImg : UIImage = UIImage(named: "whitemask.png")!
        let mask : CALayer = CALayer()
        mask.contents = maskImg.CGImage
        mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 80)
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

storyboardでUIViewを配置し、上記を関連付け、その後storyboardでUIScrollViewをUIViewの上にドラッグ＆ドロップしてUIViewの中で動くようにしました。

ご回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: redmask2.pngが、ほんとうにアルファチャンネルを持っているのか、確認なさいましたか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません、酷く勘違いしておりました。色で判別している訳では無いのですね…。ご指摘の通り、redmask2.pngはただの赤・白の画像でした。お恥ずかしい限りです。

Comment: 透過済みの別マスクで確認した所、確かにマスクをかける事ができている事を確認致しました。

Comment: ただ、この記述方法だと self.contentSize 内の mask.frame で指定した部分のみにマスクが適用されず、その結果画像内のような「0と1」しか表示されない状態になっているようです。このマスクを UIScrollView そのものにかける事は可能でしょうか？

Comment: 私はべつに質問者さんに、Scroll Viewにグラデーションをかけることを、勧めているわけじゃないんで。可能かどうかは知りませんし、そちらから提示なさったコードに対して、検証する以上の対応はできません。

Comment: 分かりました、もう少し自力で調べてみます。ご回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func scrollInit(){
    /* (省略:画像を要素として追加する動作) */

    let maskImg : UIImage = UIImage(named: "redmask.png")!
    let mask : CALayer = CALayer()
    // mask.contents = maskImg
    mask.contents = maskImg.CGImage
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 196)
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

おそらく、上のプログラムコードの中の、`CGImage`が抜けていたのが、うまくいかない原因だろうと考えられます。
（「`scrollInit()`というメソッドはどう使ってるの？」という疑問は、ここでは不問としておきます。）

---

*質問文の更新に対しての追加です。*

そもそもマスク画像（redmask2.png）は、アルファチャンネルを持っているんだろうかという疑問をもちました。
アルファチャンネルのあるPNGファイルのサンプルを載せておきます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
この画像を、Mac標準の「プレビュー」で開くと、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
このように、背景がグレーの格子縞になります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。詳しく書き直しましたので、よろしければ御確認頂ければ幸いです。